# Sql Lite Error while running Fixtures : Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider. It may not be installed

Tags: sqlite, nhibernate, tdd, nunit, fixtures

Can anybody please help to resolve this issue..
I tried saveral things after googling but yet no luck...

This error occurs while running fixtures in my project.

> NHibernate.HibernateException : **Could not create the driver from
>   NHibernate.Driver.SQLite20Driver**.
>   System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException : Exception has been
>   thrown by the target of an invocation. System.ArgumentException :
>   Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider.  It may not
>   be installed

Here is the stack trace

```
at NHibernate.Connection.ConnectionProvider.ConfigureDriver(IDictionary`2 settings)
    at NHibernate.Connection.ConnectionProvider.Configure(IDictionary`2 settings)
    at NHibernate.Connection.ConnectionProviderFactory.NewConnectionProvider(IDictionary`2 settings)
    at NHibernate.Cfg.SettingsFactory.BuildSettings(IDictionary`2 properties)
    at NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.BuildSettings()
    at NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.BuildSessionFactory()
    at MyApp.Common.Testing.UnitOfWorkTestContext.NHibernateUnitOfWorkTestContext.get_SessionFactory() in UnitOfWorkTestContext.cs: line 199
    at MyApp.Common.Testing.UnitOfWorkTestContext.NHibernateUnitOfWorkTestContext.IntialiseContainerAndUowFactory() in UnitOfWorkTestContext.cs: line 243
    at MyApp.Common.Testing.DatabaseFixture.OneTimeSetup() in DataBaseFixture.cs: line 66
    --TargetInvocationException
    at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, ref Boolean canBeCached, ref RuntimeMethodHandleInternal ctor, ref Boolean bNeedSecurityCheck)
    at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache)
    at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache)
    at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic)
    at NHibernate.Bytecode.ActivatorObjectsFactory.CreateInstance(Type type)
    at NHibernate.Connection.ConnectionProvider.ConfigureDriver(IDictionary`2 settings)
    --ArgumentException
    at System.Data.Common.DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(String providerInvariantName)
    at NHibernate.Driver.ReflectionBasedDriver..ctor(String providerInvariantName, String driverAssemblyName, String connectionTypeName, String commandTypeName)
    at NHibernate.Driver.SQLite20Driver..ctor()
```

I tried to resolve it by changing the test settings and loading required sql lite package via package manager console.
I am running 64Bit system. Can any body help me to figure out what could be the issue?

Please help,
Thanks

Comment: Are the required DLLs present in the same directory as the assembly containing the test fixtures?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the native SqLite dll in compile path or in global assembly cache?

Do you have a 64bit version of the native SqLite.dll (SqLite dll contains unmanaged code and must have the same (64/32) as you project build).

If you force your project build to 32-bit does it work then?

Comment: I am running 64bit. and the SQLite dll is in compile path.

Comment: does it run if you compile for 32 bit?

Comment: The plateform target type was set to X86 in test project build tab.
I made it 64 and it started working :)
But it was working since a year with this setting, don't know what made it wrong though..

Comment: Same exact thing happened here. The only thing I can imagine is a service pack update. See below for an additional option that worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

OK I am so sick of fixing and re-fixing this issue with each upgrade now I hope to save myself future troubleshooting by writing this down here.

I am using NHibernate **3.3.3.4000**

I am using SqlLite **3.6.23.1** but the dll file properties version says **1.0.66.0**

1. Make your unit test project platform target Any CPU (I know some people say you need to specify the architecture but I found this is not the case)
2. Reference System.Data.SQLite.dll in the project
3. Reference a companion System.Data.SQLLite.Linq.dll in the project (It should come with the System.Data.SQLite.dll) I am not sure if this dll is required by NHibernate or not.

In my app.config I need to have a system.data section:

```
<system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="System.Data.SQLite"/>
      <add name="SQLite Data Provider" invariant="System.Data.SQLite" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for SQLite" type="System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteFactory, System.Data.SQLite" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
```

I use in-memory DB and my connection string (without all the fluentnhibernate stuff) looks like:

```
Data Source=:memory:;Version=3;New=True;Pooling=True;Max Pool Size=1;
```